# Multiple Filters in SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm trying to retrieve list subscribers for a specific list with a restriction on modified date. However, it always returns all list subscribers. Are multiple filters supported in the SOAP API? Here's what I'm trying to do...

`<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">***************</fueloauth>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Status</Properties>
                <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ListID</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>100</Value>
                </Filter>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ModifiedDate</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
                    <DateValue>2014-11-30T10:30:50.092-05:00</DateValue>
                    <DateValue>2014-12-17T10:30:50.122-05:00</DateValue>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </Body>
</Envelope>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - just slightly different than how you are doing it.  Instead of two filters, you would use a `complexfilterpart`

```
<Filter xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart" >
  <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
    <Property>ListID</Property>
    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
    <Value>100</Value>
  </LeftOperand>
  <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
  <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
    <Property>ModifiedDate</Property>
    <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
    <DateValue>2014-11-30T10:30:50.092-05:00</DateValue>
    <DateValue>2014-12-17T10:30:50.122-05:00</DateValue>
  </RightOperand>
</Filter>
```

Comment: No worries - glad I could help!

Comment: Another quick question... can you add more than 2 filters? I want to also be able to filter by Status == 'Active'. Is that possible?

Comment: @Kelly J Andrews, one more question!.. How can i combine 6 or more filter conditions using 'OR' LogicalOperator